# OnBeforeRequest URL redirect in Firefox Addon (Conversion from Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, redirect, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to convert a Chrome extension of mine to Firefox. So far so good, except I had an url redirect in `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` in the Chrome extension, which is [not allowed in Firefox WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#webRequest).

Now I am unsure how to implement this in Firefox.
In the Chrome `background.js` it looked something like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    console.log('onBeforeRequest');

    var returnuri;
    returnuri = details.url;
    if ((details.url.indexOf("/malicious/") > -1) || (details.url.indexOf("/bad/") > -1)){
      //I want to redirect to safe content
      returnuri = details.url + (/\&tag=/.test(details.url) ? "" : '/safe/');
    }else{
      returnuri = details.url;
    }
    return {redirectUrl: returnuri};
  },
  {
    urls: [
      "*://malicious.com/*"
    ],
    types: ["main_frame"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: what makes you think it's not allowed in firefox addons?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities

"Redirection is not allowed in onBeforeRequest or onHeadersReceived, but is allowed in onBeforeSendHeaders."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cite the [WebExtensions docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#webRequest):

> Requests can be:
>
> - canceled only in `onBeforeRequest`
> - modified/redirected only in `onBeforeSendHeaders`
>
> ...
>
> Redirection is not allowed in `onBeforeRequest` or `onHeadersReceived`, but is allowed in `onBeforeSendHeaders`.

Well, that explains the situation pretty well. Your options are:

1. Wait until WebExtensions achieve better support for `webRequest`.

**EDIT (Dec 2018)**: This is indeed now possible. Citing [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest#Modifying_requests):

> On some of these events, you can modify the request. Specifically, you can:
>
> - cancel the request in:
>
>   - `onBeforeRequest`
>   - `onBeforeSendHeaders`
>   - `onAuthRequired`
> - redirect the request in:
>
>   - `onBeforeRequest`
>   - `onHeadersReceived`
>
> [...]

2. Cancel, and not redirect, the request if it's absolutely imperative that no connection is made at all.
3. Redirect in `onBeforeSendHeaders` instead. Considering that you're only checking the URL and that is available in that event, it shouldn't make a difference except that the TCP connection may be already established before you redirect.

   Note that the same code wouldn't work in Chrome - it doesn't expect a redirect in this request.

   As mentioned by you, unlike Chrome, redirecting to the same URL would produce a loop (because at this point the request needs to be remade from scratch).

   <del>In general, if you need to inspect something available in an earlier event and act on it later, you can flag the request in `onBeforeRequest` by saving its `requestId` and later redirecting the same request ID in `onBeforeSendHeaders`.</del> Unfortunately, the docs state that `requestId` is not supported either.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I tried doing so but am unsure how to then solve the issue of running into a loop. When I redirect in the onBeforeSendHeaders it fires the onBeforeRequest with the new uri and after that the onBeforeSendHeaders again and so on.
I could only imagine to check for the safe url within as well and only redirect if not detected which is not to easy at it is quite dynamic and not as simple as posted above. Any other elegant solution how I can avoid retriggering the sendHeaders event several times?

Comment: But the new `onBeforeSendHeaders` will have a "good" URL. You need to change your logic to only return a blocking response if the URL really needs to be changed. Of course `return {redirectUrl: request.url}` is _asking_ for loops.

Comment: yep you are right. Will reprogram to fit it like that. Thanks for the input. Helped me clear that blockage :)

Comment: supported now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#webRequest